# check provided element is within the clicked target

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I have elements as shown below

```
<div id="target" class="textarea">
 HTML is written in the form of HTML elements consisting of tags enclosed in angle
 brackets (like
 &lt;html&gt;
 ),within the web page content. HTML tags most commonly come in pairs like and ,although
 some tags, known as empty elements, are unpaired, for example
 &lt;img&gt;. The purpose of a web browser is to read HTML documents and compose them into
 visible or audible web pages. The browser does not display the HTML tags, but uses
 the tags to interpret the content of the page.
<div id="target2" class="textarea"><div id="test3"><div id="test4">Right Click Here</div> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to check whether the element I am having `("target2")` is the same element, whenever I click in the Div elements `target2` or `test2` or `test3`. Here `test2` and `test3` or contained inside `target2`.I am currently using  `$(e).is($.trim(my element)` to check whether the element I am having is the same element I am clicking. But, `e.target` returns `test4` whenever I click on the div element `target2`. But, I am actually clicking on `target2`. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your JS code?

Comment: Please show your event handling code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to test if an element is within another element

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).closest('#target2').length) {
        alert('I am within target2, or I am target2');
    }
});
```

The behavior expected in question is very unclear. Provide additional details if this is not what you are after

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d2uwp3Ln/)**</kbd>